# How to repeatedly invoke a SAS macro where the second param is the first with - and . removed?

Tags: sas, dynamic-variables, sas-macro

I have a macro that needs two parameters -- a string that can contain dashes and periods, and a cleaned-up version of the same string where any dashes and periods are replaced by underscores.

The following works:

`%let foo = abc.def;`

`%mymacro(firstpar = &foo, secondpar=%sysfunc(translate(&foo,"__","-.")));`

`%let foo = abc-def;`

`%mymacro(firstpar = &foo, secondpar=%sysfunc(translate(&foo,"__","-.")));`

...but how do I loop through a long list of such variables? Is there some standard idiom for either assigning the elements of a list to a placeholder variable one at a time and then evaluating the command, or directly substituting them into the command string (but not evaluating it until I explicitly ask for it)?

I tried using the [%DO_WHILE](http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Tight_Looping_with_Macro_Arrays) macro library, and it works great as long as the `&foo`s don't contain punctuation. If they do, it fails and no combination of quoting I tried can get it to work.

My actual macro is too long and convoluted to be practical to post here. Hopefully this general question is clear enough to be answerable:

"What is the recommended strategy for repeatedly invoking a macro whose one-off invocation looks like `%mymacro(firstpar = &foo, secondpar=%sysfunc(translate(&foo,"__","-.")));` and you have a large list of values for `foo`?"

Or maybe put another way: "What is the closest thing in SAS to R's `parse()` and `deparse()` functionality?"

Answer (score 2):

I can't relate to R's parse and deparse, as I am not familiar with them. However, I would just pass in the first parameter and create the second macro variable within the macro. See below, FIRSTPAR is as you had it in your sample. I include a TRANSLATE parameter which contains the characters which should be replaced (defaulting to '.'):

```
%macro mymacro(firstpar=,translate=.);

  data _null_;
    firstpar="&firstpar";
    translate="&translate";
    secondpar="&firstpar";
    subi=1;
    do while(length(translate)>=subi);
      secondpar=tranwrd(secondpar,substr(translate,subi,1),"_");
      subi+1;
    end;
    call symput('secondpar',secondpar);
  run;
  %put &secondpar;
%mend mymacro;
```

Replace periods and dashes:

```
%mymacro(firstpar=abc-de-fg.hi-.k,translate=.-)
```

Replace periods, dashes and commas:

```
%mymacro(firstpar=%str(abc-de,fg.hi,.k),translate=%str(.-,))
```

These two examples output the SECONDPAR macro variable to the log as:

```
abc_de_fg_hi__k
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned 'list' here so the approach will depend on how you parse this list to the macro.
If the list is already in a form which can be used directly as a macro variable, for example

```
%let foo = abc-def abc-d-af abd-c-dgf;
```

here individual parameters are delimited by space. A macro variable holds all. Then you may extract the parameters one by one:

```
 %macro mymacro(firstpar = &foo, secondpar=%sysfunc(translate(&foo,"__","-.")));
   %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&foo,' '));
          %let p1 = %scan(&foo, &i, ' ');
          %let p2 = %scan(&secondpar, &i, ' ');
          *<original macro statements>*
   %end;
```

Use `COUNTW` to get numbers of parameters, and `SCAN` to get these parameters.

If the list needs to be imported first. There are extra steps:

```
 data tmp;
 input foo $;
 datalines;
 abc-def
 abcd-def
 abc-d-af
 ;
 run;

 proc sql noprint;
   select foo into :foo separated by ' ' from tmp;
 quit;
```

Now the list has been stored to `foo`, delimited by space. Then it can be parsed into the macro above.

Comment: I don't like this solution because it uses the macro language to do something SAS is already better at with data step or other methods.  If you are forced to use the macro language (if it is for homework I guess?) then the first part is acceptable, but the steps to import the code into a macro variable are entirely extraneous - if you are already using select...into, then just write the macro call there rather than going through the %do loop.

Comment: This solution is made just for meeting what OP wants. OP didn't specify how the list is stored so we have to guess. The second part is only a possibility. The principle I obey here is to do as little as possible modification to OP's original macro, just focusing on variable manipulation.

Comment: The OP asked very clearly, "What is the recommended strategy for repeatedly invoking a macro".  What you described above is not anything close to an acceptable method for doing that.  Your solution violates one of the basic tenets of SAS programming - do not store your data in a macro variable.

Comment: Okay, I accept your point. Actually, I often do IML when there is a need to loop through a row of data. Using macro to read table one row a time and then symget/symput is also an approach. However, I still think when the data is not in a very large quantity, storing to a macro variable is not that bad as you said. Your solution (method 2) involves selecting things into a variable. Isn't it similar? By the way,I agree with DavB that the second parameter shall be generated inside macro instead of being defined as an argument. I may update the answer later.

Comment: Storing the code (the macro call) in a variable is fine - it's storing actual data I object to.  :)  As I noted, if he actually does have all of the data in one macro variable already, I don't mind the first part of your solution - I don't like it, but it's probably the right answer.  The second part is what I object to.  IML certainly is a very good solution for some things like this, though I usually don't answer in IML of course since it's an expensive add-on many people don't have - and I'm still learning it myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple question is, how do you repeatedly call a macro from existing data.  I'll preface this by saying, often you don't - you often simply do whatever in normal SAS code.  But you didn't give us any information, so perhaps you have a good reason for repeatedly calling a macro (I certainly do sometimes, despite usually trying to avoid it).

I would incorporate into this answer the answer of DavB above - don't have both values as parameters, solely use the first parameter and then translate it inside the macro to the second.

There are about a dozen ways to create a data-driven macro call; here are three.

```
%macro foo(param=);
%let second_param=%sysfunc(translate(&param,"___","-.a"));
%put &param &second_param;
%mend foo;


*Method 1: Call Execute.  This puts code in a queue to execute after the data step completes.  
    This has some advantages, namely that you can build code easily and can modify it with data step functions, 
    and some disadvantages, namely that some timing issues (when things happen internal to SAS) exist 
    and can be difficult to remember/work around.  Not used all that often as a result of those timing issues 
    but for simple things can be useful.;
data _null_;
set sashelp.class;
mcall = cats('%foo(param=',name,')');
call execute(mcall);
run;

*Method 2: PROC SQL select into.  This creates a list and stores it in a macro variable.  
    Quick and easy (much shorter code-wise) compared to the other solutions, but has one significant limitation:
    a hard limit to how many total characters can be stored in a macro variable (I forget exactly how much, but around 20,000).
    So if you are calling the macro a thousand or more times this might fail - it writes a warning to the log if so.
    Use NOPRINT with PROC SQL unless you want to see what is generated.;
proc sql;
select cats('%foo(param=',name,')') into :mcalllist separated by ' ' from sashelp.class;
quit;
&mcalllist;

*Method 3: Include file generation.  This creates an actual text file with your code in it, then you include that code.
    In some ways the most transparent - you can easily debug the code - but also a lot of lines of code to write comparatively.
    Does not have the length limitation of the PROC SQL method, although it does have the normal limitations of included code.
    The temp file is written to your WORK directory, so you can navigate to that to see the contents, and/or use a non-TEMP file
    and write it out to a directory of your choosing in order to see it.
;

filename foo temp;
data _null_;
file foo;
set sashelp.class;
mcall = cats('%foo(param=',name,')');
put mcall $;
run;
%include foo;
```